# How do I stop a user from incresing the height of TextBox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have an `<asp:TextBox TextMode="MultiLine" Height=350 Width="200">` and have elements around it.

I don't want to allow the user to change the height and width of the `asp:TextBox` because it messes with the alignment of other elements around it.

Solution?

Comment: To say anything userfull: how does the user change the size of the `asp:TextBox` ?

Comment: @Rhapsody My bad, edited the question and description.

Comment: @Rhapsody: ASP.NET's `TextBox` is a `<textarea>` if it's set to multiline. Some browsers like Safari 5 and Firefox 4 add resize handles to `<textarea>`s.

Comment: @BoltClock Ok, I'm sorry I didn't know that. But apparently you can use `resize: none;` in CSS. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome/

Comment: @Rhapsody: Yup, that's the answer. Go for it! \*points down\*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a TextBox control that is multiline not be resizable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097270/how-can-i-make-a-textbox-control-that-is-multiline-not-be-resizable)

Answer (score 4):

[Answer added for future reference]

You can use `resize: none;` in CSS to disable the resize-functionality offered by Firefox/Safari. An example and explanation can be found [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/disable-textarea-resizing-safari-chrome/).

(thanks to BoltClock)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add it in your textbox tag, you can do it like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" MWidth="245px" Height="245px" 
      TextMode="MultiLine" style="resize:none"></asp:TextBox>
```