# How can I make a TextBox control that is multiline not be resizable?

Tags: asp.net

How can I make a TextBox control that is multiline not be resizable?

I am using asp.net with c# and I can't find an option to do this

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should be able to disable textarea resizing in Chrome and Safari with this css:

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: wow, this is CSS3 feature or it was just there for all the time and I was doing that thing, which I wrote as an answer here, stupidly?

Comment: It also applies to Firefox. At least version 11 for me

Answer (score 21):

Not preferred code, but this worked for me. This style overwrites the css

```
<asp:TextBox id="tb5" TextMode="multiline" style="resize:none" width="330px" Height="50px" wrap="true" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 7):

I am using the following method and it works most on most of them;

```
.mymultitextboxclass{max-height:100px;min-height: 100px;max-width:400px;min-width:400px;}
```

then set this css class to your MultiLine Textbox. see it : http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/RKcbn/

Comment: Your solution does not remove the resize holder but works like a charm, actually I have to say it seems to be a better solution as resize:none is a css3 attribute whereas min/max-width/height is a css2 attribute (considering that css2 support is wider currently)

Comment: @detay that's relief to hear that resize:none is a CSS3 feature. I was think I completely sucked at it by doing that for months :D

Comment: For a long time I also thought it was a browser-specific tag :) http://www.css3.info/preview/resize/

Comment: thanks for the link. I sucked at my English above by writing  `I was think` :s but I meant `I was thinking` :=)

Comment: no worries. your english is just fine, and to err is human :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no such option on the control.

This completely depends on the browser and how it renders textboxes.

You can control this via the CSS [`resize`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize) property, though this is browser dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Create a CSS class as follows:

```
 .MultiLineTextBox
{
    resize: none;

}
```

Then in the code of textbox,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAdd" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" BorderStyle="Inset"
CssClass="MultiLineTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
```